# CloudDataflow can not use "google.cloud.datastore" package?

Tags: python, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-dataflow

I want to put datastore with transaction on CloudDataflow.
So, I wrote below.

```
def exe_dataflow():
....
  from google.cloud import datastore
  # call from pipeline
  def ds_test(content):
    datastore_client = datastore.Client()

    kind = 'test_out'
    name = 'change'
    task_key = datastore_client.key(kind, name)

    for _ in range(3):
        with datastore_client.transaction():
            current_value = client.get(task_key)
            current_value['v'] += content['v']
            datastore_client.put(task)

    # pipeline
....
      | 'datastore test' >> beam.Map(ds_test)
```

But, Error occured and log message was displayed as below.

```
(7b75e0ef2db229da): Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py", line 582, in do_work
    work_executor.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/executor.py", line 167, in execute
    op.start()
  ...(SNIP)...
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dill/dill.py", line 767, in _import_module
    return getattr(__import__(module, None, None, [obj]), obj)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'datastore'
```

CloudDataflow can not use "google.cloud.datastore" package?

**add 2018/2/28.**

I add --requirements_file to MyOption

```
  options = MyOptions(flags = ["--requirements_file", "./requirements.txt"])
```

and I make requirements.txt

```
google-cloud-datastore==1.5.0
```

But, Another error occurred.

```
(366397598dcf7f02): Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py", line 582, in do_work
    work_executor.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/executor.py", line 167, in execute
    op.start()
...(SNIP)...
  File "my_dataflow.py", line 66, in to_entity
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/datastore/__init__.py", line 60, in <module>
    from google.cloud.datastore.batch import Batch
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/datastore/batch.py", line 24, in <module>
    from google.cloud.datastore import helpers
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/datastore/helpers.py", line 29, in <module>
    from google.cloud.datastore_v1.proto import datastore_pb2
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/datastore_v1/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from google.cloud.datastore_v1 import types
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/datastore_v1/types.py", line 21, in <module>
    from google.cloud.datastore_v1.proto import datastore_pb2
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/datastore_v1/proto/datastore_pb2.py", line 17, in <module>
    from google.cloud.datastore_v1.proto import entity_pb2 as google_dot_cloud_dot_datastore__v1_dot_proto_dot_entity__pb2
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/datastore_v1/proto/entity_pb2.py", line 28, in <module>
    dependencies=[google_dot_api_dot_annotations__pb2.DESCRIPTOR,google_dot_protobuf_dot_struct__pb2.DESCRIPTOR,google_dot_protobuf_dot_timestamp__pb2.DESCRIPTOR,google_dot_type_dot_latlng__pb2.DESCRIPTOR,])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/protobuf/descriptor.py", line 824, in __new__
    return _message.default_pool.AddSerializedFile(serialized_pb)
TypeError: Couldn't build proto file into descriptor pool!
Invalid proto descriptor for file "google/cloud/datastore_v1/proto/entity.proto":
  google.datastore.v1.PartitionId.project_id: "google.datastore.v1.PartitionId.project_id" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto".
...(SNIP)...
  google.datastore.v1.Entity.properties: "google.datastore.v1.Entity.PropertiesEntry" seems to be defined in "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto", which is not imported by "google/cloud/datastore_v1/proto/entity.proto".  To use it here, please add the necessary import.
```

Comment: Did you add the datastore package requirement to your pipeline? [More info here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-pipeline-dependencies/)

Comment: you mean "from google.cloud import datastore"? or Should I add another code?

Comment: I mean if you specified the dependency via a requirements or setup file for your pipeline.

Comment: No I don't specify requirements and setup.Other package is installed when template is maken.But google.cloud.datastore is not installed.(I add my googlecloudopton info.)

Comment: I understood you meant!https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/dependencies-python  I have to --requirements_file to MyOption. But I run job via costom template. Where do I store requirements.txt?

Comment: I can install google.cloud.datastore to my pipeline.but another error occured.(add error messaget to my question)

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Are we not allowed to install google-cloud-datastore dependency and use it within our pipeline anymore?

I know that we are supposed to use the datstore I/O API for bulk grabs to start the pipeline, for instance, but what about when I need to grab individual items from datastore at arbitrary compute nodes in the pipeline?

Further, this used to work?

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way to interact with Cloud Datastore from a Cloud Dataflow Pipeline is to use the [**Datastore I/O**](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/datastore-io) API, which is available through the Dataflow SDK and provides some methods to read and write data to a Cloud Datastore database.

You can find detailed documentation for the Datastore I/O package for Dataflow SDK 2.x for Python in [this other link](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/pydoc/2.3.0/apache_beam.io.gcp.datastore.html). The [`datastore.v1.datastoreio` module](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/pydoc/2.3.0/apache_beam.io.gcp.datastore.v1.datastoreio.html) is the specific module that you want to use. There is plenty of information in the links I am sharing, but in short, it is a connector to Datastore that uses `PTransform` to **read** / **write** / **delete** a `PCollection` from Datastore using the classes **`ReadFromDatastore()`** / **`WriteToDatastore()`** / **`DeleteFromDatastore()`** respectively.

You should try using it instead of implementing the calls yourself. I suspect this may be the reason for the error you are seeing, as a Datastore implementation already exists in the Dataflow SDK:

```
"google.datastore.v1.PartitionId.project_id" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto".
```

***UPDATE:***

It looks like those three classes collect several mutations and executes them in a single transaction. You can check that in the [code describing the classes](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/pydoc/2.3.0/_modules/apache_beam/io/gcp/datastore/v1/datastoreio.html#WriteToDatastore.to_upsert_mutation).

If the aim is to retrieve (`get()`) and then update (`put()`) a Datastore entity, you can probably work with the [`write_mutations()` function](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/pydoc/2.3.0/_modules/apache_beam/io/gcp/datastore/v1/helper.html#write_mutations), which is [described in the documentation](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/pydoc/2.3.0/apache_beam.io.gcp.datastore.v1.helper.html#apache_beam.io.gcp.datastore.v1.helper.write_mutations), and you can work with a full [batch of mutations](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/data/rpc/google.datastore.v1#mutation) performing the operations you are interested in.

Comment: I want to get()->put() with transactional.Can ReadFromDatastore() / WriteToDatastore() / DeleteFromDatastore() APIs use transaction?

Comment: I edited the answer providing some more information about the "transactional" nature of the DatastoreI/O module.

Comment: I tried the same code but the error with the entity.proto remains. So, how to use datastoreio.WriteToDatastore PTransform? The virtual environment is setup as instructed by Apache Beam GCP. PS: the error occures in the import statement for the WRiteToDatastore class.