# Fetch datastore entity by id inside of a Dataflow transform

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-dataflow

I have 2 datastore models:

```
class KindA(ndb.Model):
    field_a1 = ndb.StringProperty()
    field_a2 = ndb.StringProperty()

class KindB(ndb.Model):
    field_b1 = ndb.StringProperty()
    field_b2 = ndb.StringProperty()
    key_to_kind_a = ndb.KeyProperty(KindA)
```

I want to query `KindB` and output it to a csv file, but if an entity of `KindB` points to an entity in `KindA` I want those fields to be present in the csv as well.

If I was able to use `ndb` inside of a transform I would setup my pipeline like this

```
def format(element):  # element is an `entity_pb2` object of KindB
    try:
        obj_a_key_id = element.properties.get('key_to_kind_a', None).key_value.path[0]
    except:
        obj_a_key_id = None


    # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< HOW DO I DO THIS
    obj_a = ndb.Key(KindA, obj_a_key_id).get() if obj_a_key_id else None

    return ",".join([
        element.properties.get('field_b1', None).string_value,
        element.properties.get('field_b2', None).string_value,
        obj_a.properties.get('field_a1', None).string_value if obj_a else '',
        obj_a.properties.get('field_a2', None).string_value if obj_a else '',
    ]


def build_pipeline(project, start_date, end_date, export_path):

    query = query_pb2.Query()
    query.kind.add().name = 'KindB'
    filter_1 = datastore_helper.set_property_filter(query_pb2.Filter(), 'field_b1', PropertyFilter.GREATER_THAN, start_date)
    filter_2 = datastore_helper.set_property_filter(query_pb2.Filter(), 'field_b1', PropertyFilter.LESS_THAN, end_date)
    datastore_helper.set_composite_filter(query.filter, CompositeFilter.AND, filter_1, filter_2)

    p = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)
    _ = (p
         | 'read from datastore' >> ReadFromDatastore(project, query, None)
         | 'format' >> beam.Map(format)
         | 'write' >> apache_beam.io.WriteToText(
                    file_path_prefix=export_path,
                    file_name_suffix='.csv',
                    header='field_b1,field_b2,field_a1,field_a2',
                    num_shards=1)
         )
    return p
```

I suppose I could use `ReadFromDatastore` to query all entities of `KindA` and then use `CoGroupByKey` to merge them, but `KindA` has millions of records and that would be very inefficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the reccommendations in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49130224/4458510

I created the following utils, which were inspired by the source code of

`DatastoreWriteFn` in `apache_beam.io.gcp.datastore.v1.datastoreio`

`write_mutations` and `fetch_entities` in `apache_beam.io.gcp.datastore.v1.helper`

```
import logging
import time
from socket import error as _socket_error

from apache_beam.metrics import Metrics
from apache_beam.transforms import DoFn, window
from apache_beam.utils import retry
from apache_beam.io.gcp.datastore.v1.adaptive_throttler import AdaptiveThrottler
from apache_beam.io.gcp.datastore.v1.helper import make_partition, retry_on_rpc_error, get_datastore
from apache_beam.io.gcp.datastore.v1.util import MovingSum
from apache_beam.utils.windowed_value import WindowedValue
from google.cloud.proto.datastore.v1 import datastore_pb2, query_pb2
from googledatastore.connection import Datastore, RPCError

_WRITE_BATCH_INITIAL_SIZE = 200
_WRITE_BATCH_MAX_SIZE = 500
_WRITE_BATCH_MIN_SIZE = 10
_WRITE_BATCH_TARGET_LATENCY_MS = 5000


def _fetch_keys(project_id, keys, datastore, throttler, rpc_stats_callback=None, throttle_delay=1):
    req = datastore_pb2.LookupRequest()
    req.project_id = project_id
    for key in keys:
        req.keys.add().CopyFrom(key)

    @retry.with_exponential_backoff(num_retries=5, retry_filter=retry_on_rpc_error)
    def run(request):
        # Client-side throttling.
        while throttler.throttle_request(time.time() * 1000):
            logging.info("Delaying request for %ds due to previous failures", throttle_delay)
            time.sleep(throttle_delay)

            if rpc_stats_callback:
                rpc_stats_callback(throttled_secs=throttle_delay)

        try:
            start_time = time.time()
            response = datastore.lookup(request)
            end_time = time.time()

            if rpc_stats_callback:
                rpc_stats_callback(successes=1)
            throttler.successful_request(start_time * 1000)
            commit_time_ms = int((end_time - start_time) * 1000)
            return response, commit_time_ms
        except (RPCError, _socket_error):
            if rpc_stats_callback:
                rpc_stats_callback(errors=1)
            raise

    return run(req)

# Copied from _DynamicBatchSizer in apache_beam.io.gcp.datastore.v1.datastoreio
class _DynamicBatchSizer(object):
    """Determines request sizes for future Datastore RPCS."""
    def __init__(self):
        self._commit_time_per_entity_ms = MovingSum(window_ms=120000, bucket_ms=10000)

    def get_batch_size(self, now):
        """Returns the recommended size for datastore RPCs at this time."""
        if not self._commit_time_per_entity_ms.has_data(now):
            return _WRITE_BATCH_INITIAL_SIZE

        recent_mean_latency_ms = (self._commit_time_per_entity_ms.sum(now) / self._commit_time_per_entity_ms.count(now))
        return max(_WRITE_BATCH_MIN_SIZE,
                   min(_WRITE_BATCH_MAX_SIZE,
                       _WRITE_BATCH_TARGET_LATENCY_MS / max(recent_mean_latency_ms, 1)))

    def report_latency(self, now, latency_ms, num_mutations):
      """Reports the latency of an RPC to Datastore.

      Args:
        now: double, completion time of the RPC as seconds since the epoch.
        latency_ms: double, the observed latency in milliseconds for this RPC.
        num_mutations: int, number of mutations contained in the RPC.
      """
      self._commit_time_per_entity_ms.add(now, latency_ms / num_mutations)


class LookupKeysFn(DoFn):
    """A `DoFn` that looks up keys in the Datastore."""

    def __init__(self, project_id, fixed_batch_size=None):
        self._project_id = project_id
        self._datastore = None
        self._fixed_batch_size = fixed_batch_size
        self._rpc_successes = Metrics.counter(self.__class__, "datastoreRpcSuccesses")
        self._rpc_errors = Metrics.counter(self.__class__, "datastoreRpcErrors")
        self._throttled_secs = Metrics.counter(self.__class__, "cumulativeThrottlingSeconds")
        self._throttler = AdaptiveThrottler(window_ms=120000, bucket_ms=1000, overload_ratio=1.25)
        self._elements = []
        self._batch_sizer = None
        self._target_batch_size = None

    def _update_rpc_stats(self, successes=0, errors=0, throttled_secs=0):
        """Callback function, called by _fetch_keys()"""
        self._rpc_successes.inc(successes)
        self._rpc_errors.inc(errors)
        self._throttled_secs.inc(throttled_secs)

    def start_bundle(self):
        """(re)initialize: connection with datastore, _DynamicBatchSizer obj"""
        self._elements = []
        self._datastore = get_datastore(self._project_id)
        if self._fixed_batch_size:
            self._target_batch_size = self._fixed_batch_size
        else:
            self._batch_sizer = _DynamicBatchSizer()
            self._target_batch_size = self._batch_sizer.get_batch_size(time.time()*1000)

    def process(self, element):
        """Collect elements and process them as a batch"""
        self._elements.append(element)
        if len(self._elements) >= self._target_batch_size:
            return self._flush_batch()

    def finish_bundle(self):
        """Flush any remaining elements"""
        if self._elements:
            objs = self._flush_batch()
            for obj in objs:
                yield WindowedValue(obj, window.MAX_TIMESTAMP, [window.GlobalWindow()])

    def _flush_batch(self):
        """Fetch all of the collected keys from datastore"""
        response, latency_ms = _fetch_keys(
            project_id=self._project_id,
            keys=self._elements,
            datastore=self._datastore,
            throttler=self._throttler,
            rpc_stats_callback=self._update_rpc_stats)
        logging.info("Successfully read %d keys in %dms.", len(self._elements), latency_ms)

        if not self._fixed_batch_size:
            now = time.time()*1000
            self._batch_sizer.report_latency(now, latency_ms, len(self._elements))
            self._target_batch_size = self._batch_sizer.get_batch_size(now)

        self._elements = []
        return [entity_result.entity for entity_result in response.found]


class LookupEntityFieldFn(LookupKeysFn):
    """
    Looks-up a field on an EntityPb2 object

    Expects a EntityPb2 object as input

    Outputs a tuple, where the first element is the input object and the second element is the object found during the
    lookup
    """
    def __init__(self, project_id, field_name, fixed_batch_size=None):
        super(LookupEntityFieldFn, self).__init__(project_id=project_id, fixed_batch_size=fixed_batch_size)
        self._field_name = field_name

    @staticmethod
    def _pb2_key_value_to_tuple(kv):
        """Converts a key_value object into a tuple, so that it can be a dictionary key"""
        path = []
        for p in kv.path:
            path.append(p.name)
            path.append(p.id)
        return tuple(path)

    def _flush_batch(self):
        _elements = self._elements
        keys_to_fetch = []
        for element in self._elements:
            kv = element.properties.get(self._field_name, None)
            if kv and kv.key_value and kv.key_value.path:
                keys_to_fetch.append(kv.key_value)
        self._elements = keys_to_fetch

        read_keys = super(LookupEntityFieldFn, self)._flush_batch()

        _by_key = {self._pb2_key_value_to_tuple(entity.key): entity for entity in read_keys}

        output_pairs = []
        for input_obj in _elements:
            kv = input_obj.properties.get(self._field_name, None)
            output_obj = None
            if kv and kv.key_value and kv.key_value.path:
                output_obj = _by_key.get(self._pb2_key_value_to_tuple(kv.key_value), None)
            output_pairs.append((input_obj, output_obj))
        return output_pairs
```

The Key to this is the line `response = datastore.lookup(request)`, where:

- `datastore = get_datastore(project_id)` (from `apache_beam.io.gcp.datastore.v1.helper.get_datastore`)
- `request` is a `LookupRequest` from `google.cloud.proto.datastore.v1.datastore_pb2`
- `response` is `LookupResponse` from `google.cloud.proto.datastore.v1.datastore_pb2`

The rest of the above code does things like:

- using a single connection to the datastore for a dofn bundle
- batches keys together before performing a lookup request
- throttles interactions with the datastore if requests start to fail

(honestly I don't know how critical these bits are, I just came across them when browsing the apache_beam source code)

The resulting util function `LookupEntityFieldFn(project_id, field_name)` is a `DoFn` that takes in an `entity_pb2` object as input, extracts and fetches/gets the key_property that resides on the field `field_name`, and outputs the result as a tuple (the fetch-result is paired with the input object)

My Pipeline code then became

```
def format(element):  # element is a tuple `entity_pb2` objects
    kind_b_element, kind_a_element = element

    return ",".join([
        kind_b_element.properties.get('field_b1', None).string_value,
        kind_b_element.properties.get('field_b2', None).string_value,
        kind_a_element.properties.get('field_a1', None).string_value if kind_a_element else '',
        kind_a_element.properties.get('field_a2', None).string_value if kind_a_element else '',
    ]


def build_pipeline(project, start_date, end_date, export_path):

    query = query_pb2.Query()
    query.kind.add().name = 'KindB'
    filter_1 = datastore_helper.set_property_filter(query_pb2.Filter(), 'field_b1', PropertyFilter.GREATER_THAN, start_date)
    filter_2 = datastore_helper.set_property_filter(query_pb2.Filter(), 'field_b1', PropertyFilter.LESS_THAN, end_date)
    datastore_helper.set_composite_filter(query.filter, CompositeFilter.AND, filter_1, filter_2)

    p = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)
    _ = (p
         | 'read from datastore' >> ReadFromDatastore(project, query, None)
         | 'extract field' >> apache_beam.ParDo(LookupEntityFieldFn(project_id=project, field_name='key_to_kind_a'))
         | 'format' >> beam.Map(format)
         | 'write' >> apache_beam.io.WriteToText(
                    file_path_prefix=export_path,
                    file_name_suffix='.csv',
                    header='field_b1,field_b2,field_a1,field_a2',
                    num_shards=1)
         )
    return p
```